# Invalid AES key length: N bytes - Java

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo XML la cual deseo cifrarla por que en ahí se encuentra información de la cuenta del usuario, encontré el siguiente código para realizar el cifrado y descifrado:

CryptoUtils.java:

```
public class CryptoUtils {

private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

public static void encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
        throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
        throws CryptoException {
    doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
}

private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile,
        File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    try {
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);
         
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);
         
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
         
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
         
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
         
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
}
```

CryptoException.java:

```
public class CryptoException extends Exception {

public CryptoException() {
}

public CryptoException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
    super(message, throwable);
}
}
```

Metodo para cifrar:

```
public boolean cifrarArchivo() {
    final String key = "x";
    File inputFile = new File("siet-user-information.xml");
    File encryptedFile = new File("document.encrypted");
    File decryptedFile = new File("document.decrypted");
    
    try {
        CryptoUtils.encrypt(key, inputFile, encryptedFile);
        CryptoUtils.decrypt(key, encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
        return true;
    } catch (final CryptoException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error al cifrar: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error: `Error al cifrar: Error encrypting/decrypting file: Invalid AES key length: 1 bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se produce aquí :

```
 Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
```

de acuerdo a el error:

> Error encrypting/decrypting file: Invalid AES key length: 1 bytes

el error se puede generar cuando la longitud del array especificado (`key.getBytes()`)no es la adecuada para el algoritmo que usas, en tu caso la longitud es de solo 1 byte! , cuando debería ser me parece de 16 (128 bits), 24 (192 bits) o 32 (256 bits) bytes.

Puedes verlo en la documentación:

[**Clase AES**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24001_01/apirefs.1111/e10668/oracle/security/crypto/core/AES.html)